# Pushing data into an array using a function in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have this array with a number of birthdates for a set of different players.
For these birthdates I've coded a function with the birthdate as the parameter, that when called upon will return how old that player is.

Now I want to automate this process. To do this I have tried making a for loop, where for each iteration I want to push date into a new empty array, where I use the push() method with the function I coded to assign the given age of the player based on each players birthdate, so that I can combine them later.

This is the function

```
function getAge (dateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m = 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() <  birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}
```

This is my attempt at automating the process.

```
var playerAgeDate = ["Jan 8, 1990", "Mar 3, 1995", "Jun 10, 1991", "Jun 19, 1996", "Jul 26, 1988", "Mar 17, 1986", "Nov 10, 1985", "Dec 13, 1994", "Jan 24, 1996", "Jul 14, 1997", "Jan 2, 1991", "Apr 14, 1997", "Mar 17, 1987", "Mar 10, 1989", "Jul 2, 1999", "Jun 17, 1991", "Apr 17, 1996", "Mar 11, 1991", "Jun 20, 1989", "May 5, 1999", "Mar 25, 1993", "Dec 15, 1988", "Jul 17, 1997", "Mar 11, 1999", "Jul 4, 1997", "Jul 8, 1983"];
var playerAgeYear = [];
for (var i = 0; i < playerAgeYear.length; i++) {
  playerAgeYear.push(getAge(playerAgeDate[i]));
 }
```

I expected it to assign the correct values in an order that would make it easy for me to combine the two values for later use, but the array is still empty.

Comment: `i < playerAgeYear.length;` <-- you are comparing against the length of an empty array, so the loop will just finish immediately because 0 < 0 is false. You likely wanted `i < playerAgeDate.length` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a mistake in for loop you put the wrong array in stop condition of your loop.
You should the array with the date: `playerAgeDate` and not `playerAgeYear` which is empty.

Moreover has chris p bacon said in the comment you assigned `m = 0` instead of testing his value `m == 0`

This will works

```js
function getAge (dateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m == 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() <  birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}

var playerAgeDate = ["Jan 8, 1990", "Mar 3, 1995", "Jun 10, 1991", "Jun 19, 1996", "Jul 26, 1988", "Mar 17, 1986", "Nov 10, 1985", "Dec 13, 1994", "Jan 24, 1996", "Jul 14, 1997", "Jan 2, 1991", "Apr 14, 1997", "Mar 17, 1987", "Mar 10, 1989", "Jul 2, 1999", "Jun 17, 1991", "Apr 17, 1996", "Mar 11, 1991", "Jun 20, 1989", "May 5, 1999", "Mar 25, 1993", "Dec 15, 1988", "Jul 17, 1997", "Mar 11, 1999", "Jul 4, 1997", "Jul 8, 1983"];
var playerAgeYear = [];
for (var i = 0; i < playerAgeDate.length; i++) {
  playerAgeYear.push(getAge(playerAgeDate[i]));
 } 
 console.log(playerAgeYear)
```

Comment: He's also assigning m = 0 in if

Comment: Yupp, that's the solution! Thanks a lot haha

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the length from the original array `playerAgeDate`, not from the empty target array `playerAgeYear`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < playerAgeDate.length; i++) {
```

```js
function getAge (dateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m !== 0 || m === 0 && today.getDate() <  birthDate.getDate()) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}

var playerAgeDate = ["Jan 8, 1990", "Mar 3, 1995", "Jun 10, 1991", "Jun 19, 1996", "Jul 26, 1988", "Mar 17, 1986", "Nov 10, 1985", "Dec 13, 1994", "Jan 24, 1996", "Jul 14, 1997", "Jan 2, 1991", "Apr 14, 1997", "Mar 17, 1987", "Mar 10, 1989", "Jul 2, 1999", "Jun 17, 1991", "Apr 17, 1996", "Mar 11, 1991", "Jun 20, 1989", "May 5, 1999", "Mar 25, 1993", "Dec 15, 1988", "Jul 17, 1997", "Mar 11, 1999", "Jul 4, 1997", "Jul 8, 1983"];
var playerAgeYear = [];

for (var i = 0; i < playerAgeDate.length; i++) {
    playerAgeYear.push(getAge(playerAgeDate[i]));
} 
 
console.log(playerAgeYear);
```

Comment: He's also assigning m = 0 in if

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it, you are just using the wrong array to determine the stop condition of your `for` loop. You need to use `playerAgeDate` length, not `playerAgeYear` as this one starts out empty.

```
var playerAgeDate = ["Jan 8, 1990", "Mar 3, 1995", "Jun 10, 1991", "Jun 19, 1996", "Jul 26, 1988", "Mar 17, 1986", "Nov 10, 1985", "Dec 13, 1994", "Jan 24, 1996", "Jul 14, 1997", "Jan 2, 1991", "Apr 14, 1997", "Mar 17, 1987", "Mar 10, 1989", "Jul 2, 1999", "Jun 17, 1991", "Apr 17, 1996", "Mar 11, 1991", "Jun 20, 1989", "May 5, 1999", "Mar 25, 1993", "Dec 15, 1988", "Jul 17, 1997", "Mar 11, 1999", "Jul 4, 1997", "Jul 8, 1983"];
var playerAgeYear = [];
for (var i = 0; i < playerAgeDate.length; i++) {
  playerAgeYear.push(getAge(playerAgeDate[i]));
 }
```

As pointed out by @chrispbacon, you are also using the assignement operator `=` in your `if` condition, instead of probably intended comparison operator `<`.

This might lead to unexpected results.

Comment: He's also assigning m = 0 in if

Comment: Jesus Christ how did I overlook it!
Thanks a lot!